# Which "not" is not in the proper place: "Not only does (not) she (not) know, but also ..."

Tags: word-order, negation, subject-verb-inversion

I know that whenever we bring "not only" at the beginning of a sentence, what comes after it has to be in question form.

Now, I'm having a problem with the negative form of this question.
Which one of the following sentences is correct?

> Not only doesn't she know, but also ...

or

> Not only does she not know, but also ...

Comment: They are both grammatical.

Comment: Hello, navid.h. Why not avoid pathological examples and use plain English? Read OB's answer.

Comment: One of the _not_’s in the question title is ungrammatical; the other _not_ is not. But the _not_ that is not grammatical is not there in the question itself. Why not?

Comment: @Janus That was funny. So many *not*s  :)  When I was writing the title, I tried to put both of the sentences in the question title. So I ended up having too many *not*s. In the question itself, however, I separated the sentences to avoid the confusion and to make it easier to understand.

Comment: The trouble is that _not only does not she know_ is not the same as _not only doesn’t she know_ – one is grammatical, the other isn’t.

Comment: @Janus Which one isn't ? Why aren't they identical? I didn't know; :(

Comment: @navid.h Just like in regular questions. “Does she not know?” and “Doesn’t she know?” are equivalent and grammatical. “Does not she know?” is ungrammatical in present-day English.

Comment: @Janus I agree that we never hear anyone saying "Does not she know?". But it doesn't mean it is ungrammatical. "Doesn't" is just the short version of "Does not".

Comment: @navid.h No, that’s not how it works. It **is** ungrammatical. Contractions with _-n’t_ can’t necessarily just be uncontracted directly – in the case of subject-auxiliary inversion, the verb and its negation get contracted ‘across’ the subject, and uncontracting them without moving the negation back after the subject results in an ungrammatical construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what mathematicians call a pathological example - one sought out to test the rules to their limit. So on the one hand this specific case may not be covered in the grammars but on the other hand we may be able to learn something about grammar by looking at it.

First we have to look at the question form without the "not only". We find that there are two valid forms:

> Does she not know?
>   Doesn't she know?

Why we are allowed different word order when we want to abbreviate I have no idea. Maybe it is answered in another question.

But whatever the reason, it is nonetheless a fact.

It is another fact (and perhaps there is an explanation on this site for this too but it may be something to do [with this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order)) that you use the inverted (or question) form after "not only" so both forms given in the question are logically valid. And indeed they both sound fine to me too.

Comment: I think the reason for the different word orders comes from the fact that the abbreviation combines the verb and its negation in the statement "She doesn't know" which is then inverted to form a question treating "doesn't" as a verb including the negation. Without the abbreviation the statement is "She does not know" and the inversion leaves the negation where it is becoming "Does she not know?" because it's not part of the verb. Whether "doesn't" _should_ be treated as a verb in this way is above my pay grade, but it is.

Comment: @BoldBen That is a pretty convincing argument. I am not someone who believes these things happen as a result of a single cause but I think you may have identified the most significant cause. I think rules about grammar are often misused to argue that something can't happen. So if someone tells you that you are wrong because *doesn't* isn't a verb then just ask them what proportion of the people responsible for the development of Modern English knew what a verb was.

Comment: I agree that there's rarely a single cause for this sort of thing. The other point is that the 'rules' of English grammar are formed from the practice of the natual language. The language came first, the formal analysis came much later and the 'rules' only describe how the language works, not define it. So far as I know only Esperanto has rules that were defined before the language was used!

Answer (score 0):

> **Not only does she not know**

is a little more formal, and perhaps slightly better, than

> **Not only doesn't she know**

But I'm worried about how you would *continue* the sentence. Double negatives sound awkward, so we tend (in BrE at least) to avoid the *not only - but also* formula when the verb is negative.

If we find we HAVE embarked on such a formula we often don't bother finishing it 'properly': "*Not only does she not know: she doesn't even care.*" This might not be grammatically perfect but it is colloquial. It would be better and simpler to say,

> She neither knows nor (cares)

or perhaps

> She doesn't know and she doesn't (care).

If, on the other hand, the stress in your example is on **"she"**, then you need to rewrite it. There are several better ways to say, "Not only does she not know, but also he doesn't." "She doesn't know but neither does he." Or less emphatically, "Neither of them knows." (Or "know". It is much discussed!)

Comment: “Not only does she not know, but also he doesn’t” is highly awkward to me, bordering on ungrammatical. _Also_ and _so_ both become _neither_ or _nor_ with a negation: “Not only does she not know, but he doesn’t either”. There is also nothing ungrammatical about “Not only does she not know – she doesn’t even care” (the colon is misapplied, I feel, but that’s punctuation, not grammar). There is no necessity, grammatical or otherwise, for a _not only_ clause to be followed by a _but also_ clause.